# Pip installed successfully but still " no module" error when importing

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have created a new pip package on the pypi site "sndboxapi", I can do pip install `sndboxapi` but i can't import it in code.

I have created a range of environments but they all install OK but not just don't allow me to use the module.

```
robot@Robot:~/Documents$ python3 -m venv test

robot@Robot:~/Documents$ source test/bin/activate

(test) robot@Robot:~/Documents$ which python
```

> /home/robot/Documents/test/bin/python

```
(test) robot@Robot:~/Documents$ python
```

> Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)

```
(test) robot@Robot:~/Documents$ pip --version
```

> pip 9.0.1 from /home/robot/Documents/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>   (python 3.6)

```
(test) robot@Robot:~/Documents$ pip install sndboxapi
```

> Collecting sndboxapi
>
> Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/74/b2ef5a92483209b1a3225ffcba180a25bac517f7b2670eb0dabe43f6fa7f/sndboxapi-1.3-py3-none-any.whl
>
> Installing collected packages: sndboxapi
>
> Successfully installed sndboxapi-1.3

```
(test) robot@Robot:~/Documents$ pip list
```

> DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future.
>   You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a
>   format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to
>   disable this warning. pip (9.0.1)
>
> pkg-resources (0.0.0)
>
> setuptools (39.0.1)
>
> sndboxapi (1.3)

```
(test) robot@Robot:~/Documents$ python
```

> Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)

```
>>> import sndboxapi
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "< stdin >", line 1, in
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sndboxapi'

I expect the output to allow me to import the module and then allow me to call the functions.

Comment: Have you tried installing by `pip3 install sndboxapi`?

Comment: the pip3 version is the same as the pip command in the env:
 pip3 install sndboxapi
Requirement already satisfied: sndboxapi in ./test/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Comment: can you check if the files for `sndboxapi` is present in the `/home/robot/Documents/test/lib/python<your_python_version>/site-packages/`?

Comment: TIL the folder within my code "scripts" that contains the code is the name i must refer to when importing in the code Thanks for your help. I will update this.

Comment: You are not importing the module correctly. `from sndbox import sndboxapi`. The installation looks fine though.

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://pypi.org/project/sndboxapi/) says:

```
from sndbox import sndboxapi
```